# How to change section link (using the id attribute) in a HTML page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

I have a page with [this bootstrap navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) on it and I have some content headers and paragraphs on my page like so:

```
<h1>Links</h1>
<a href="#para1">P1</a>
<a href="#para2">P2</a>
<a href="#para3">P3</a>

<div id="para1">
    <h1>Paragraph 1</h1>
    <p>Here is come text...</p>
</div>
<div id="para2">
    <h1>Paragraph 2</h1>
    <p>Here is come text...</p>
</div>
<div id="para3">
    <h1>Paragraph 3</h1>
    <p>Here is come text...</p>
</div>
```

When I click the link, the header will go to the top of the page. This means it will be behind the navbar.

How can I make the header appear just *below* the navbar when the link is clicked rather than behind it?

This should apply to all the links on the page.

Comment: I considered that, but it makes the page move the wrong way - so in my example you'd be presented with the `Paragraph 2` header when you click on the `P1` link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, when you click a link, the browser will scroll to the start of that element. So to get round this, we need to push the *contents* of the element down so they display below the navbar.

The obvious way to do this is to add `padding` to the top of each `paraX` set to the height of the navbar. This will work but then you will an unwanted big gap above each section. The trick here is then use a negative `margin` of the same size to pull the whole element back up to where it was. This has the effect of navigating the page to `50px` above the `h1`, so it clears the navbar.

For a pure CSS solution, you have to assume that the navbar is a certain height, so the default `50px`. You could also use JavaScript to dynamically create a CSS rule based on the calculated height - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37510948/dynamically-add-rules-to-css-file) for details.

Adding this should fix the issue (I would also give `para1`,`para2`,`para3` a shared css class, such as `para`, to simplify things):

```
#para1, #para2, #para3, .para {
  padding-top:50px;
  margin-top:-50px;
}
```

**Example snippet**

```css
.para {
  padding-top:50px;
  margin-top:-50px;
}

/* for testing - to force a scroll and mark end of p */
p {
  padding-bottom:400px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="container">
      
      <h1>Links</h1>
      <a href="#para1">P1</a>
      <a href="#para2">P2</a>
      <a href="#para3">P3</a>

      <div id="para1" class="para">
          <h1>Paragraph 1</h1>
          <p>Here is come text...</p>
      </div>
      <div id="para2" class="para">
          <h1>Paragraph 2</h1>
          <p>Here is come text...</p>
      </div>
      <div id="para3" class="para">
          <h1>Paragraph 3</h1>
          <p>Here is come text...</p>
      </div>
      
    </div>
```